# Bigquery Simba odbc driver - Receive "Unable to find keyfile" message when set KeyFile parameter as plain text object

Tags: c#, google-bigquery, odbc

I am using simba odbc driver to connect to bigquery.

I use DSN-less Connection mode on a Non-Windows Machine and with a Service Account.

The string connection looks like this:

```
Driver=Simba Google BigQuery ODBC Connector;
OAuthMechanism=0;Email=application-service-
account@iam.gserviceaccount.com;KeyFile={
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "testdata",
  "private_key_id": "XXX",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----XXX-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "application-service-account@iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "XXX",
  "auth_uri": "https://XXX",
  "token_uri": "https://XXX",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://XXX",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://XXX"
};Catalog=testdata;
```

I am using KeyFile parameter and not KeyFilePath so that I can specify the key in plain text object as specified in the [documentation](https://storage.googleapis.com/simba-bq-release/odbc/Simba%20Google%20BigQuery%20ODBC%20Connector%20Install%20and%20Configuration%20Guide-3.0.0.1001.pdf) page 97.

Unfortunately I get the message :

> ERROR [28000][Simba][BigQuery] (8706) Unable to open keyfile: { "type": "service_account",...

Why do I have this error?